# Help identifying a font family

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I'm all new at Graphic Design, so correct me if you can. I found this graphic picture today from Earth Hour's website for 2012:

[image]

I really want some fonts that looks a bit like them. Someone having a clue which family they are in? And maybe know about some similar fonts? Appreciate any thoughts and ideas.

Comment: Do you have a link to the site by any chance? I went to earthhour.org but it was set up for 2013.

Comment: I did not find the right date in the archive, but it looks pretty much the same. @Brendan http://web.archive.org/web/20120114070927/http://earthhour.fr/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So last year's typography looks to be the same as [this years](http://earthhour.fr/) (2013):

[image]

If the text is selectable, you can figure out what font it is by "Inspecting Element":

[image]

Looks like the font is WWF Regular, which I'm assuming is a proprietary font.

If you want something similar, check out [Interstate Condensed Regular](http://www.fonts.com/font/font-bureau/interstate/condensed-volume-one) or [Myriad Pro Condensed Regular](http://www.fonts.com/font/adobe/myriad/semibold-semi-condensed). [League Gothic](http://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/league-gothic) or [Oswald](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Oswald) could maybe do the trick if you're looking for free fonts.

I just tried it with the service [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) and found that [Alternate Gothic](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/efscangraphic/alternate-gothic-sb/no-two/) suits your needs pretty well too.

Comment: Wow, thank you. This was indeed very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Bebas Neue.